# How does the custom grid page size work?

Tags: grid, report, rally

We use the Rally custom grid App to display user stories based on a query.  I really don't understand the "Page Size" value.

If the query returns 100 rows and the "Page Size" is set to ten (10).  It appears that the page does indeed stop at ten rows.

Shouldn't I see a "Next Page" button / icon / etc>?  This would allow me to see the next ten.

This "Page Size" allows values 200 and under?  Why is the max value 200?  Can I alter this max to say 500?

Thanks in advance
Jim

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the custom grid used to have a paging toolbar at the bottom that looked like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, that appears to no longer be an option. As it currently functions, setting the pagesize to the max (200) is the only logical selection because it allows you to see as many entries in the grid as possible. However, I'll second the argument that 200 is sometimes not enough.

Comment: Connor, Thank you for your comment.  The image or screen shot you attempted didn't show on your reply.  Thanks anyway.